# What's the syntax for selecting a range of lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

What's the syntax for selecting a range of lines?

I want to run a command over lines 1405 until 1700.

And one from 1405 until the end of file, without wanting to look up that number.

Update: Is it possible to select a range from the current line to Nth line?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this (replace d with your command)

```
:1405,1700d
```

and

```
:1405,$d
```

Answer (score 5):

- Go to line 1405 by typing: `1405G`.
- Press `V` to switch to VISUAL LINE mode and then go to line 1701 by typing: `1701G`.
- Now your lines are selected, you can run a command on them. For example, to replace `foo` with `bar` type: `:s/foo/bar/`.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct for the specific use case, but this is the better answer for the actual question of literally selecting a range.

Answer (score 3):

For your update: use `.,N` where N is the line you want.

(and in case you have further updates, check out `:he range`).

Comment: RTFM instead of just asking? Crazy concept :) But yeah, quite helpful indeed.

Comment: worth a look :)

Comment: `.,$s///` replace something from current line downwards, thank you!